# Regular expression to extract fractions

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex to match the fractions of format `[0-9]\/[1-9]{1,2}` in a given string.

Below is an example:

```
my_str = "This is a 1/2 1/4. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for 1/2hour." # A free text

def replace_fractions(text):
    fraction_dict = {
        '1/2': 'half',
        '1/4': 'quarter',
        '3/4': 'three quarters',
        '2/3': 'two thirds',
    }
    _tmp = ' '.join([fraction_dict.get(w, w).strip() for w in text.split()])
    return _tmp

current_result = replace_fractions("This is a 1/2 1/4. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for 1/2hour.")
```

**current_result:**

`"This is a half 1/4. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for 1/2hour."`

**expected_result:**

`"This is a half quarter. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for half hour."`

It is clear that regex needs to be used to handle cases like `1/2/3` or `1/4.` or `1/2hour`.

But, this `[0-9]\/[1-9]{1,2}` matches everything. What will be the right regex to handle these cases.

**Note**: The regex need to only handle the above cases. All extreme cases can be ignored (or will be re-edited after expert comments)

Comment: I can suggest a solution without using regex if you want

Comment: should start the denominator range from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @bhansa: yes - edited the question

Comment: @AmirHmZ: that will be great to know how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following `return` in your method:

```
return re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}(?!/?\d)', lambda x: fraction_dict.get(x.group(), x.group()), text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DS1aZg). Note the space between `half` and `hour` is missing, because it was missing in the input. You would need to add more logic to add the space only in expected cases.

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)` - a digit or a digit and `/` are not allowed immediately on the left
- `[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}`  - a digit, `/` and 1 or 2 digits
- `(?!/?\d)` - immediately to the right, there should not be `/` + digit or just a digit.

[Full code snippet](https://ideone.com/DS1aZg):

```
import re
my_str = "This is a 1/2 1/4. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for 1/2hour." # A free text

def replace_fractions(text):
    fraction_dict = {
        '1/2': 'half',
        '1/4': 'quarter',
        '3/4': 'three quarters',
        '2/3': 'two thirds',
    }
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)[0-9]/[0-9]{1,2}(?!/?\d)', lambda x: fraction_dict.get(x.group(), x.group()), text)

current_result = replace_fractions("This is a 1/2 1/4. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for 1/2hour.")
print(current_result)
# => This is a half quarter. Press 1/2/3. He drove a car for halfhour.
```